# How can I update PBI Cloud App without creating a new one

Tags: powerbi

I have uploaded a report to PBI Cloud with several bookmarks and different data models like tables and different charts. Now I made some changes to this report and published it by replacing the existing one. Some charts were deleted and some new were newly added. When navigating directly to the report in PBI cloud I can see the changes. But the changes are not applied for the App which is connected with that report.

Is there any further step needed to perform so that the models in the PBI Cloud "App" get also updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the workspace there is an Update app button, that you need to click,

[image: Update app]

This will take you through the process of republishing the app

Comment: How could I miss that...
Perfect, thank you!